# в foreach есть ли изобажение

Tags: php, html5

Здравствуйте! хочу вывести фото которые есть в бд и которых нет то есть если фотография есть в бд то выводит изображения которое есть если нет то выводит просто фото по умолчанию. Проблема в цикле находит хоть одну фото которой не и ставит везде по умолчанию вот как я пытаюсь сделать

```html
if($result->rowCount() > 0){
    while ($myrow = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $id = $myrow["id"];
      $job_vacancy = $myrow["job_vacancy"];
      $my_content = $myrow["my_content"];
      $catalog = $myrow["catalog_small"];
      $filename = $myrow["filename_small"];


$file = explode(",", $filename);
$short_link = substr($my_content, 0, 94);
foreach ($file as $key) {
  echo "
  <div class='col-sx-12 col-md-4'>
     <div class='card'>";
       if(file_exists($catalog.$key)){
       echo "<img class='card-img-top' src='".$catalog."/".$key."' alt='Card image cap'>";
     }
     else{
      echo "<img src='https://2oq.ru/my_room/img/avatar.png'  class='img-thumbnail'> ";
      }
      echo "
         <div class='card-block'>
         <h4 class='card-title'>".$job_vacancy."</h4>
         <p class='card-text'>".$short_link."</p>
         <a href='https://2oq.ru/info/?id=".$id."' class='btn btn-primary'>Подронее</a>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
";
}
    }
  }
```

или так

```html
if($result->rowCount() > 0){
    while ($myrow = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $id = $myrow["id"];
      $job_vacancy = $myrow["job_vacancy"];
      $my_content = $myrow["my_content"];
      $catalog = $myrow["catalog_small"];
      $filename = $myrow["filename_small"];


$file = explode(",", $filename);
$short_link = substr($my_content, 0, 94);
foreach ($file as $key) {
  echo "
  <div class='col-sx-12 col-md-4'>
     <div class='card'>
       <img class='card-img-top' src='".$catalog."/".$key."' onerror = 'this.style.display = 'none'' alt='Card image cap'>
         <div class='card-block'>
         <h4 class='card-title'>".$job_vacancy."</h4>
         <p class='card-text'>".$short_link."</p>
         <a href='https://2oq.ru/info/?id=".$id."' class='btn btn-primary'>Подронее</a>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
";
}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
echo "
  <div class='col-sx-12 col-md-4'>
     <div class='card'>
       <img class='card-img-top' src='".$catalog."/".$key."'";?> onerror = "this.src = 'https://2oq.ru/my_room/img/avatar.png'"<?php echo " alt='Card image cap'>
         <div class='card-block'>
         <h4 class='card-title'>".$job_vacancy."</h4>
         <p class='card-text'>".$short_link."</p>
         <a href='https://2oq.ru/info/?id=".$id."' class='btn btn-primary'>Подронее</a>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
";
```

но если кто даст ответ с foreach то спасибо я просто отделил php onerror = "this.src = 'https://2oq.ru/my_room/img/avatar.png'"